# List all the functions of a class by order of writing

Tags: python, list, class, function

How can I have a list with all the functions of a class but not alphabetically reordered ?
Because actually I have that :

```
[ foo.__dict__.get(a) for a in dir(foo) if isinstance(foo.__dict__.get(a), types.FunctionType) ]
```

And it return me a list but reordered ...
I've also tried with a decorator:

```
def decorator ():
    listing = []
    def wrapped (func):
        listing.append(func)
        return func
    wrapped.listing = listing
    return wrapped
```

That's fine but, I need to add a decorator on each function of my class ... May be you have some tricks ?

Comment: `dict`s don't preserve order. so if you want in order of appearance you *may have to* parse using regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module docs. Function objects have  `func_code` attr, and (according to docs - didn't test it yet), `func_code` should have `co_firstlineno` attribute, which will be the number of the first line of code in source file.

So please try something like:

```
def getListOfClassFunctions(foo):
    '''foo - a class object'''
    funcList = [ foo.__dict__.get(a) for a in dir(foo) if isinstance(foo.__dict__.get(a), types.FunctionType)]
    funcList = filter(lambda x: x.func_code.co_filename == foo.__module__, funcList)  # Thanks Martijn Pieters for a hint!
    return sorted(key=lambda x: x.func_code.co_firstlineno, funcList)
```

**Edited** to wrap the whole snippet in a function and to return only functions defined in the same module as class.

Comment: This is actually very clever, this works as long as all the functions have been defined within the same class body (not bolted on later).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I was aware that dynamically added functions won't work well here. But the task of ordering all functions by their position in file is not well defined for dynamically added functions :)

Comment: Yup, I quite agree, just pointing that small detail out. You could use `.co_filename` to keep the various functions apart and provide at least a stable ordering that makes *some* sense. :-) Edgecase, I know, still admiring the idea.